# Composite filter support in Objectify

Tags: objectify

We are using objectify v4 and we want to get entities of following query
Select * from Kind Where public=true || (public = false && owner = id);

Seems it is possible in Composite Queries and are executing with native datastore queries.

I do not see any documentation in objectify(vn) about support of this.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to v5. I don't recall exactly when, but at some point Objectify got the ability to pass in a `Filter` object directly to the `filter()` method. You can pass in a `CompositeFilter`